# What catalog format from webtranslateit.com to select for LinguiJS that will work with plurals?

Tags: linguijs

I am trying to switch from i18next to LinguiJS due to big bundle size of i18next.

I use webtranslateit, which supports these [formats](https://webtranslateit.com/en/docs/file_formats/).

I currently use i18next json v3 format on webtranslateit:
[image: screenshot from webtranslateit]

What format to select on webtranslateit that will work with multiple variations of plurals? (not just singular and single plural)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [LinguiJS documentation](https://lingui.js.org/ref/catalog-formats.html) they seem to work with Gettext PO files and JSON files. Both these formats are supported by the WebTranslateIt tool ([Gettext PO](https://webtranslateit.com/docs/file_formats/gettext_po) and [JSON](https://webtranslateit.com/docs/file_formats/json)) and they both support plural forms.